# Minimum connecting time

Tags: transit, short-connections, saudi-arabia, dmm

I have recently booked my flight from Karachi to Jeddah via Dammam. The flight arrives at Dammam at 13:55 and leaves at 16:00. I have booked these tickets for Umrah.

My question is whether the connection time of 2 hours 5 minutes will be enough for all the processes at Dammam airport. Can immigration be done in this time and can we catch our flight to Jeddah?

If not, please mention the alternatives.

Comment: Moiz Ali i have spoken to a reputable travel umrah agent in karachi , he said the only problem is 2 hours connection wont be enough. At least you need 4 hours stay at dammam. Airline also might refuse borading with short connection stay

Comment: alternative is change to at least 4 hours stay at Dammam, Saudi Arabian airlines have frequent flights from Dammam to Jeddah

Answer (score 6):

**Re-book your trip, because with this itinerary you will be refused entry to Saudi Arabia**

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=SA&SECTION=pa&SUBSECTION=wa&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the Quran of airlines, passengers arriving for Umrah **cannot** enter Saudi Arabia at Dammam or Riyadh. You will **only** be admitted at Jeddah, Medinah or Yanbu

Comment: I think the above answer is incorrect, i have spoken to reputable travel agent umrah visa holder can enter dammam with connecting flight to Jeddah, also Saudi airline page suggests that umrah traveler can enter through dammam

Comment: this is confirmation umrah traveller can enter through Dammam http://www.saudiairlines.com/portal/site/saudiairlines/menuitem.d9a467d070ca6c65173ff63dc8f034a0/?vgnextoid=70f443a9afdbe210VgnVCM100000d59618acRCRD

Comment: @AliAwan Er, no, that only confirms what IATA says: "Umrah visa holders should enter and depart from King Khalid International Airport in Riyadh, King Abdulaziz International Airport in Jeddah, Prince Mohammed Bin Abdulaziz Airport in Madinah or Prince Abdulmohsin Bin Abdulaziz Airport in Yanbu only without passing through other Saudi airports."

Comment: @AliAwan And in any case, airlines go by Timatic, and if it says there you cannot enter the country, you will not be let on the plane

Comment: @AliAwan Mail timediting@iata.org and link any information you have found, and see what they say. They get their information **directly from the Saudi border authorities and will check directly with them**

Comment: @ crazydre the Saudi airline link I just posted , when you open a link read umrah traveller paragraph 3 , for umrah traveller entering and departing dammam airport

Comment: @AliAwan Because it was allowed in the past (until 2012 I think) but not anymore. Like I said, Timatic has the current information and is what's used by airlines